# Getting data from comboBox and use it to get data in onother combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I have a two comboboxes in my app. One of them, `cmb1`, is binding with a table called Branches, and the other one, `cmb2`, is binding with another table called `teachers`. The relation between them is many to many in a table called `subjectteachers`. I need to know how to  take the Id of selected `cmb1` 
and search in table `subjectteachers` with that id and get the name from table `teachers` to put it in `cmb2`

```
CollegeContext cd = new CollegeContext();
        Branch SectionCB = CBTypeOfSection.SelectedItem as Branch;

        var query = from b in cd.Branches
                    where (from st in cd.SubjectTeachers
                           where (st.IdBranch == SectionCB.Id &&
                          (from t in cd.Teachers
                           where
                           (t.Id == st.IdTeacher)
                           select t.Name) select st))
                           select b;

        TeachersComboBox.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: var query = cd.Subjectteachers.Where(x=>x.IdBranch==SectionCB.Id).Select(x=>x.Teacher);

Comment: it works .....thanks a lot ..... can i ask another  one?

Comment: if i want to get some data in teacher table not all of it 
for ex: idwork ==5 in table teacher in the same combobox

Comment: TeachersComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "idwork";

Comment: i will put it in answer so you can accept it

Comment: i tried to vote but it shows this phrase......Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: you can mark my answer as correct @Hady Salah

Comment: I tried but am sorry my reputation still 6 so I can't

Answer (score 0):

this is called lambda its really helpfull hope you like it.

```
   var query = cd.Subjectteachers.Where(x=>x.IdBranch==SectionCB.Id).Select(x=>x.Teacher);

    TeachersComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "idwork";
```